# CALayer explicit animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, caanimation

Guys I'm trying to perform a CABasicAnimation (just for the test purposes) following the [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html)

There's a piece of code:

```
CABasicAnimation* fadeAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
fadeAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
fadeAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
fadeAnim.duration = 5.0;
[theLayer addAnimation:fadeAnim forKey:@"opacity"];

// Change the actual data value in the layer to the final value.
theLayer.opacity = 0.0;
```

Which tells that I should actually change a property at the end. But it seems not working fine(it changes opacity immediately) - the duration is not 5 (I changed it to 5 for better visibility) so the animation is not CABasicAnimation but implicit.
It only works when I set `theLayer.opacity = 0.0;` BEFORE I add the animation to `layer`. Am I doing something wrong or it is a bug in docs?
P.S running the latest XCode, iOS 7.1 simulator.

Comment: Change the property before you do the animation or use the animation delegate functions to do it when it's over.

Comment: Add fadeAnim.removedOnCompletion = NO; and [fadeAnim setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards]; the final opacity should be set at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the model layer before adding the animation.

```js
CABasicAnimation* fadeAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
fadeAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
fadeAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
fadeAnim.duration = 5.0;

// Change the actual data value in the layer to the final value.
theLayer.opacity = 0.0;

[theLayer addAnimation:fadeAnim forKey:@"opacity"];
```